# Spring MVC - Mapping one error to multiple Fields

Tags: java, spring-mvc

In my bean I have a list

```
List<SomeClass> values = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();

SomeClass{
 int a;
 int b;
 int c;
}
```

My validation code -

```
int i =0
for(SomeClass entry: values){
  if(entry.getA() < 0 && entry.getB() < 0 && entry.getC() > 0){
       bindingResult.addError(newFieldError("bean", "values[" + i"].a", values.get(i).getA(),false,new String []{"error.code"}, null, null));
  }
}
```

`error.code` maps to String "**If C is greater than zero then A and B must be greater than zero**"

The problem is i want to map error code to `values[i].a` as well as `values[i].b` so that those two fields are highlighted on UI.

The `FieldError` constructor accepts `String field` and not `String [] fields`.

Is there any way to add two error fields for same error?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just call `addError()` twice, with a 2nd `FieldError` for .b ?

Comment: The would add another error message on UI. I want to show only one error message and highlight two fields

Comment: OK gotcha, sorry don't have a good answer for that one, but maybe 1 global error message instead (not field-specific FieldError) plus a FieldError for both with an empty error message? Sounds like hack :-)

Comment: Tried passing null and blank string as error message but spring mvc is smart enough to throw exception on that :) for every error, error message is required.

Answer (score 0):

Once you detect the condition for which you want to display the Validation message with multiple fields highlighted, you can use the below code to display the common/global error message:

```
if ("your error condition"){
    errors.reject("your.error.code");
}
```

Then update the model with the boolean flags corresponding to the fields that should be highlighted.

```
model.addAttribute("xFieldHighlighted", true);
model.addAttribute("yFieldHighlighted", true);
```

Then use JavaScript to highlight the fileds. JQuery example below:

```
var xFieldHighlighted = '${xFieldHighlighted}';
var yFieldHighlighted = '${yFieldHighlighted}';

if (xFieldHighlighted == 'true'){
    $('#xFieldID').addClass('cssError');
}

if (yFieldHighlighted == 'true'){
    $('#yFieldID').addClass('cssError');
}
```

Comment: it should be errors.reject("your.error.code"), not #rejectValue, as rejectValue method takes at least two arguments.

Comment: @SachinKumar - thanks for pointing out. I've updated the answer.